# How to createin ES an index with different analyzers for search and indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to set up index with with different analyzers for indexing and search.
The SENSE I type the following code:

```
PUT my_index
{
   "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
         "properties" : {
            "content" : {
               "type" : "string",
               "index": "analyzed",
               "analyzer": "my_index_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings" : {
      "number_of_shards" : 1,
      "analysis" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "my_filter" : {
                        "type" : "pattern_capture",
                        "preserve_original" :1,
                        "patterns" : ["(([a-z]+)(\\d*))"]                                          
                             }},
                "index_analyzer" : {
                     "my_index_analyzer" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "standard",
                        "type" : "custom",
                        "filter" : ["my_filter"]
                              }},
                "search_analyzer" : {
                    "my_search_analyzer" : {
                        "type" : "custom",
                        "tokenizer" : "standard",
                        "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to work; the ES instance always returns me an error like

> MapperParsingException[mapping [my_type]]; nested:
>   MapperParsingException[Analyzer [my_index_analyzer] not found for
>   field [content]]

Answer (score 1):

Change your analyzer part to

```
"analyzer": {
        "my_index_analyzer" : {
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "type" : "custom",
          "filter" : ["my_filter"]
        },
        "my_search_analyzer" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "standard",
          "filter" : ["standard", "lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
```

and change the mapping part to:

```
"properties" : {
        "content" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "index_analyzer": "my_index_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "my_search_analyzer"
        }
      }
```